# Improvising chords when playing blues

Tags: chords, improvisation, blues

Can you tell me what kind of chords should I add that would make my blues playing much more colourful? For example, when playing in the key of G minor, I usually play G min11, A dim7 that adds some colours to my playing.

Would you advise me to play some other chords or scales over blues that would make my playing more strong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to answer your question I would look at different chords you can put in the progression rather than adding extensions to the chords.

The turnarounds at the end of Blues forms can vary with different chords.

Look at turnarounds like ii-V7 leading to the beginning of the form that can be used.

Here is a link to some examples of progressions: https://www.premierguitar.com/articles/19663-style-guide-essential-blues-progressions

Comment: I think this is a good idea. You can have a lot of fun and add a lot of interest in turnarounds, intros, transitions between chords etc. But sometimes (not always) other band members need a heads up.

Answer (score 5):

Think of the name of a chord. That can be one of the new chords to play in a colourful blues. 7ths, 9ths, 11ths 13ths, sus, aug., dim., b5, b9, #9 to name some of the simpler, more common ones. It would be facile to say play this or that. It will depend where you are in the blues, which chord is next, and lots of other factors.

You must listen to far more blues than you already have, by many different artists. Google 'blues sequences', and at least a dozen different ideas will pop up.

Comment: _Think of the name of a chord. That can be one of the new chords to play in a colourful blues_  - +1000 - LOL - that's the nice thing about blues!